# Post data parameters with url in Cefsharp chromiumwebbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using a web interface within my c# windows form application using Cefsharp libraries.I can load my tab page with the browser using the following code

```
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();         
        Cef.Initialize(settings);            
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/myproject/login.php"); 
        tab_web.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

But I am unable to post the login credential to the page (metod is POST) so that i can register the session and the user can direct access to his profile from the application.
UPDATE

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/test.php");
        chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
        tab_web.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;    
    }
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
         InitializeChromium();
     }
    public  void load_browser()
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        byte[] request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data1=sssss&data2=sssss");
        PostTest.Navigate( chromeBrowser, "http://localhost/test.php", request, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        tab_gis.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
    }
}
public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        if (request.Url == "http://localhost/test.php")
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        var postData = new PostData();
        MessageBox.Show("HHHH");
        postData.AddData("test=123&data2=456");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.PostData = postData;
        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }
}
```

screenshot of the reply from the httpbin is as attached[image: In this the data posted is embedded in the data array][image]

Meanwhile the form data submission should be as follows [image: the username and password data is attached to the form array]

I changed the content type to multipart/form-data , text, xml, etc. nothing helped me.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#load-url-with-postdata you'll have to perform a successful request before you can call LoadRequest.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland, Being a beginner in C#, I cant integrate the request example code to my existing code. Can you elaborate the comment?

Comment: To call LoadRequest you need to already have a valid render process, which means you need to successfully load another URL first. Alternatively you can append post data to initial request, you can take the example from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#useragent and instead of setting the header append post data. You can create a new post data object http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_PostData.htm

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#load-url-with-postdata has been updated with a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. the OnBeforeResourceLoad function call is successfull. but the postdata is not reaching the website.The site is showing the 'Method Not Allowed' message as no post data is reached.

Comment: In the remote debugging, the request method is shown as GET

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: Have you tried the exact example and confirmed that works? Your example is incomplete, there's code missing,  no idea which code you are actually using.

Comment: @amaitland I am sorry bro, your code alone is working fine. I am checking for the fault in my code. As of now I am managed the code working with a timer which reloads the browser with post data after 100 milli sec. I will get back to you and will update the working code once the fault is rectified. Once again thanks for ur support.

Comment: If you are still having problems then edit your question and show the exact code you are using. Remove any unnecessary code.

Comment: The code is working fine when I am using the httpbin.org url. But when I am using it with my localhost/test.php, it gives the error of undefined variable 'test'. My php file just consist of     <?php
echo $_POST['test'];
?>

Comment: You may need to set the ContentType, possible other headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#Example for one post example. I'd suggest you look at a POST Request in DevTools and see what headers are set.

Comment: I can see from the reply of the httpbin, the data posted is set to the 'data' array, meanwhile when I am using with a form submission, the data is set to the 'form' array, which can be accessed by $_POST['variableName'].

Comment: Try setting the content type header

Comment: You need to use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type for typical from.

Comment: Done. Thanks bro. The content-Type is changed to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it works fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to **Amaitland**. He gives the necessary directions with examples through which I got the solution of this problem. I am posting the working code here for help to any other Cefsharp user.

```
    public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        //Where possible only intercept specific Url's
        //Load http://httpbin.org/post in the browser and you'll
        //see the post data
        if (request.Url == "http://httpbin.org/post")
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
        }

        //Default behaviour, url will be loaded normally.
        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
                //Modify the request to add post data
        //Make sure to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST
        var postData = new PostData();

        postData.AddData("test=123&data=456");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.PostData = postData;
        //Set the Content-Type header to whatever suites your requirement
        request.SetHeaderByName("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", true);
        //Set additional Request headers as required.

        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }
}

//Load http://httpbin.org/post in the browser to see the post data
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://httpbin.org/post");
browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```

For more details, pl refer
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#load-url-with-postdata